# What mongo query can i use to get distinct value counts of a specific field for a date range?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say i have a fruit field. I do a date range query from 3/19 to 3/21 but want to get a count for each day of what different types of fruit people ate, and how many times did they eat it for each day.

Here's what I have so far.

```js
db.getCollection('fruits').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "dates": {
        "$gte": new Date(2018, 02, 19, 00, 00, 00),
        "$lt": new Date(2018, 02, 21, 00, 00, 00)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        year: {
          $year: "dates"
        },
        month: {
          $month: "dates"
        },
        day: {
          $dayOfMonth: "dates"
        },
        "fruitField": "$fruits"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
]
```

Edit:

An expected output would be something like:
19th:
Oranges: 17
Apples: 19
Pears: 8

20th: 
Oranges: 6
Pears: 4

21st:
Oranges:3
Apples: 10
Pears: 4

Comment: Try `{
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        year: {
          $year: "dates"
        },
        month: {
          $month: "dates"
        },
        day: {
          $dayOfMonth: "dates"
        },
        fruit:"$fruits"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDb 3.6 and newer, you can leverage the use of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator and a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline to get the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('fruits').aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "dates": {
            "$gte": new Date(2018, 02, 19, 00, 00, 00),
            "$lt": new Date(2018, 02, 21, 00, 00, 00)
        }
    } },
    {  "$group": {
        "_id": {  
            "fruit": { "$toLower": "$fruits" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$dates" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.day",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.fruit",
                "v": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$replaceRoot": { 
        "newRoot": { 
            "$mergeObjects": [ 
                { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }, 
                "$$ROOT" 
             ] 
        } 
    } },
    { "$project": { "counts": 0 } } 
])
```

---

For older versions, the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step can be used effectively to evaluate the counts based on the `fruits` field value. Your overall aggregation pipeline can be constructed as follows to produce the result in the desired format:

```
db.getCollection('fruits').aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "dates": {
            "$gte": new Date(2018, 02, 19, 00, 00, 00),
            "$lt": new Date(2018, 02, 21, 00, 00, 00)
        }
    } },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { "$dayOfMonth": "$dates" },             
            "Oranges": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$fruits", "Oranges" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "Apples": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$fruits", "Apples" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "Pears": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$fruits", "Pears" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            } 
        }  
    }
])
```

---

For unknown and possible fruit values, you could adopt a different pipeline:

```
db.collection('fruits').aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "dates": {
            "$gte": new Date(2018, 02, 19, 00, 00, 00),
            "$lt": new Date(2018, 02, 21, 00, 00, 00)
        }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$dates" },
            "fruit": { "$toLower": "$fruits" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.day",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "fruit": "$_id.fruit",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    } }
])
```